# Disable same-origin policy for chrome-extension:// uri scheme (extension content)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm packaging an HTML5 app as a Chrome extension declaring its content as 'web_accessible_resources' and including "https://example.com/*" in 'permissions'.

Is there any way the packaged content (accessible from chrome-extension://MY_APP/*) can get content from "https://example.com/*"?

I'd rather keep this extension structure than splitting the page into a content script and a hosted page.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, then you'd just need an ajax call.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external